# Cannot add subquery to query

Tags: cakephp

I am getting error when I am doing this

```
$excludedFlows = $this->FlowsPredefined->find('all',[
                        'conditions' => [
                            'category' => self::INCREASE_CUSTOMER_LOYALTY_FLOWS_CATEGORY,
                            'is_new' => 1,
                            'channel' => 'all'
                        ]
                    ])
                    ->select('id')
                    ->all();
                    $conditions['FlowsPredefined.id NOT IN'] = $excludedFlows;
```

The error is :

> Impossible to generate condition with empty list of values for field
> (`FlowsPredefined`.`id`)

The `excludedFlows` variable is not empty. I have 6 results in it. How to execute NOT IN in cakePHP ?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or run `bin/cake version`) - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a query, but a result set, as you're calling `all()`, and result sets are not supported as condition values.

Either do not call `all()` if you want to actually use a subquery, or, if applicable (you don't want to do this with huge numbers or results), extract the IDs into an array, like `->all()->extract('id')->toList()`.